# Is having many partition key in azure table storagea good design for read queries?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I know that having many partition keys reduce the batch processing (EGT) in the Azure Table Storage. However I wonder to know whether there is any performance issue in terms of reading as well or not? For example, if I designed my Azure Table such that every new entity has a new partition key and I end up having 1M or more partition keys. IS there any performance disadvantege for read queries?

Comment: [This session](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK4702) from Ignite talks about best practices for Azure table storage to optimize performance.

Answer (score 2):

If the most often operation done by you is Point Query (PartitionKey and RowKey specified), the unique-partition-key design is quite good. However if your querying operation is usually Table Scan (No Partition Key specified), the design will be awful.

You can refer to chapter "Design for querying" in [Azure Table Design Guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/) for the details.

Comment: let's say I'm mostly concern about point queries. I have two options for designing the partition key and row id. LEt's say I have a 14 alpha numeric for each entity in my system. The first 4 chars represent each customer. option 1) 4 char as the partition key and the remaining 10 as the row id a,d option 2 )all 14 chars as the partition key. IS there any difference in terms of the performance?

Comment: Is it possible that one customer can produce plenty of traffic? If so, I'd prefer option 2 to avoid hot traffic in one partition key. In Azure Storage Table, a partition key can only be served in one server, while multiple partition key can be load balanced into multiple server when necessary.

Comment: So, if I go for the option 2 and have the 14 chars as the partition key, and issue a query which filters on only the partition key, is it still considered as a point query (because the partition keys are unique)? I got a hunch that there is a hashing applied on the partitioned keys under the hood and that may cause this type of query not to be a point query.

Comment: Why not filter row key as well? If you specify both partition key and row key in a query, it will be a point query.

Comment: The problem is there may not be anything else to specify as the RowKey! Can a unique partition ID be a point query? 
my other question is, can I query based on a pattern in RowKey? e,g, rowkeys starting with "ABC"? and my last question, if I have a PartitionKey (which is unique) and a partially specified RowKey and select the top(1), is this a point query?

Comment: Actually, you can even specify a constant value for row key or share the same value between partition key and row key. For your question "can I query based on a pattern in RowKey", the answer is in server query you can only compare the row key with a value (=, >, <, etc.), if you would like to match row key by regex, you have to do the matching in client side. For your last question, it's not a point query.

Answer (score 1):

Point query is the most efficient query to retrieve a single entity by specifying a single PartitionKey and RowKey using equality predicates. If your PartitionKey is unique, you may consider using a constant string as RowKey to enable you to leverage point query. The choice of design also depends on how you plan to read/retrieve your data. If you always plan to use point query to retrieve the data, this design makes sense.

Please see “New PartitionKey Value for Every Entity” section in the following article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables.aspx. In short, it will scale very well since our storage system has an option to load balance several partitions. However, if your application requires you to retrieve data without specifying a PartionKey, it will be inefficient because it will result a table scan.
Please me an email @ ascl@microsoft.com, if you want to discuss further on your table design.